# Using stream as input to an async queue in Node.js, how to make sure that queue.drain is called only once

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-async

I will be reading a series of inputs from a stream, and perform a HTTP GET request per input. To avoid creating too many connections at a time, I am using [async.queue](https://github.com/caolan/async#queue) to queue up these inputs.

After all inputs are read (`end` emitted to the stream), I would like to collect previous results and generate an overview.

I am currently using `queue.drain` for this purpose. But `queue.drain` may be called multiple times in my case, since the process could be blocked on input and the queue will be empty when this happens.

So, is there anything in the async library that ensures `queue.drain` is called only once when dealing with streams? I don't mind switching to another control flow as long as this functionality could be realized.

Answer (score 1):

Just add the `drain` handler when you receive the `end` event on your readable stream.

```
var s = new SomeReadableStream();
var q = queue(your_callback, 1);

s.on('end', function() {
  // Beware: if the queue is already empty, the drain callback will never be called,
  // we have to check this by ourselves
  if (q.running() === 0 && q.length() === 0) {
    drain_cb();
  }
  else {
    q.drain = drain_cb;
  }
});
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution but I wonder what the point of assigning the handler to q would be then rather than invoking it yourself.