# Node Pipes Handle Input

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, node-streams

I am piping data from a textfile to another pipe which is downloading images from some urls. Now as expected this sends a large number of requests in quick succession and remote server shuts me down. I would like to handle next chunk only after the first is processed.
My code is:

```
read.pipe(JSONStream.parse('*'))
.pipe(es.map(function (d, cb) {
    download_images(x,y)
       .then(function(r) ...)
       .fail(function(r)  ...)
       .fin(function(f) cb())
 })
.pipe(xyz)
```

Since I have just started looking into streams, I might have missed a very simple point, or in my zeal to use streams I could have ignored a better approach

- Extremely Large json file
- Download images with a delay

Comment: You can try calling `read.pause()` right before calling `download_images()` and then call `read.resume()` right before you call `cb()`

Comment: @idbehold that was the first thing I tried, it didn't seem to work....I think I did some shoddy googling cuz I found the solution on stackoverflow http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20145700/using-stream-as-input-to-an-async-queue-in-node-js-how-to-make-sure-that-queue

Comment: @idbehold yes you are right, I had to use read.resume and read.pause. Using async.queue allowed me to make multiple requests in parallel. This questions is now resolved, I can accept your answer if you care to add it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call `read.pause()` right before calling `download_images()` and then call `read.resume()` right before you call `cb()`.